# How to check json object with distinctUntilChanged before subscribing to observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I want to subscribe to observable only when the value of my JSON object which I am receiving from observer subject change:

```js
 searchedName = '';


  filters = {
  "page": 1,
  "perPage": 10,
  "sortOrder": "asc",
  "tag": "allUsers",
  "sortBy": "firstname"
}
  getUsers(e)
  {
    console.log("searched")
    const searchedKeyword = this.searchedName.trim();
    if(searchedKeyword !== '')
    this.filters['name'] = searchedKeyword
    this._service.triggerCallForUsers(this.filters)
  }
   ngOnInit()
{
  //Initially called to load users..
   this._service.triggerCallForUsers(this.filters)

   //Subscribe to fetch users
    this._service.startFetchingUsers$
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe((filters) => {
        console.log("filters", filters)
        if (filters) {
          this._service.getUsersByFilter(filters)
            .subscribe(
              users => {
                console.log('users', users);

              },
              error => {}
            );
        }

      })
}
```

Where filters are:

Is this possible?

Trying to solve as below:

```js
.distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => {
  console.log('compare', b['name'], a['name'], b['name'] === a['name']);
  return a === b
})
```

// when first time subscribe 
output:- no output for compare

> //When I add 's' searchedName field i.e filters which is sent to
>   next() will contain
>
> filters['name']
>
> output: - compare s undefined false
>
> // If I change searchedName to 'sd':
>
> output:- compare sd sd true.

**Update:**

```
   <input type="text" (keyUp.enter)="getUsers($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchedName">
```

Service:

In service I call next() on observable:

```
private startFetchingUsers = new BehaviorSubject < any > (null);
startFetchingUsers$ = this.startFetchingUsers.asObservable();



triggerCallForCareGroup(filter) {

    this.startFetchingUsers .next(filter);
  }
```

Comment: what version of rxjs are you on?

Comment: "rxjs": "5.5.6" as per my package.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need deep equality, try using for example [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual) from lodash.

Also you have too much logic in `subscribe` - consider using [`do`/`tap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do) for side-effects and [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) for merging other Observables.

```
import { isEqual } from 'lodash';

this._service.startFetchingUsers$
    .distinctUntilChanged(isEqual)
    .do(filters => console.log("filters", filters))
    .mergeMap(filters => this._service.getUsersByFilter(filters))
    .do(users => console.log('users', users))
    .subscribe({
        error(error) {
            console.error(error);
        },
    });
```

> when I change name parameter in filter json I get updated value a['name'] and b['name'] as same.

This suggest there might also be problem somewhere else in your code. Can you share the code where you call `startFetchingUsers.next(newFilters)`?

**Update**

You are mutating the `this.filters` object and therefore you are not seeing changes because `a === b` always holds. The object itself is the same! Use shallow copy like this: `this._service.triggerCallForUsers({ ...this.filters })`

Comment: m1ch4ls Thanks. I have updated Post. Can you please review.

Comment: When I am changing keys of object then a['name'] should not be equal to b['name']. How come they both print same output? If object keys are same that does not mean object key values are same. I am unable to understand. I have never used spread syntax before need to study that how I can use it. Thanks for help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Well, `distinctUntilChanged` holds reference to the last object and you change it and provide it again - therefore the held and provided objects are the same. It is the same reference...